# How to connect a catalog to Whatsapp Manager via api?

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am able to create a catalog and insert products into it, but now I have to connect that catalog to whatsapp manager via api.

Unfortunately I did not find, within the meta documentation, which is the right endpoint to call to connect the catalog and WhatsApp manager.

So what documentation, if any, should I follow for this task?